# ImageMagick - Can %d be used together with image property percent escapes?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm encountering behavior using ImageMagick's image property percent escapes that I can't explain. Consider this minimal example that exhibits the problem:

```
convert rose: 'rose_%d.png'
# Resulting filename: rose_0.png (as expected)

convert rose: -set filename:mysize "%wx%h" 'rose_%[filename:mysize]_%d.png'
# Resulting filename: rose_70x46_%d0.png
# Why is '%d' in the output filename?
# Expected: rose_70x46_0.png

convert rose: -set filename:mysize "%wx%h" 'rose_%d_%[filename:mysize].png'
# Resulting filename: rose70x46.png
# Expected: rose_0_70x46.png
```

Relevant documentation:
https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes

Can `%d` be used together with image property percent escapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can %d be used together with image property percent escapes?

Only if it comes before `%[filename:`. Looking [at the source code](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/image.c#L1647); it appears to be a `case` statement. The order of precedence allow for field width & `%d`, but once `%[` is trapped, it stops checking on closing brace `]` -- or error.

Might be worth jumping over to the [developer forums](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) to discuss this behavior.

You can work around it by moving the index order over to the `filename:mysize` placeholder.

```sh
$ convert rose: -set filename:mysize "%wx%h_%p" rose_%[filename:mysize].png
#=> rose_70x46_0.png
$ convert rose: wizard: -set filename:mysize "%wx%h_%p" rose_%[filename:mysize].png
#=> rose_70x46_0.png rose_480x640_1.png
```

Comment: Thanks. My 3rd example _does_ put the `%d` before the `%[filename:` and still creates an erroneous filename. But, if I change the 3rd example to use `%01d` it works.

Your other workaround is good too. Unfortunately,  `%p` can't handle padding directives like `%02p` the way `%d` can.